# gnuplot display issue - red hat

Tags: linux, gnuplot, redhat

I have a gnuplot script to track the variation of certain parameters with time. This works fine for all desktops on our linux network apart from one:

Here is the code and the output

```
        gnuplot -geometry 1024x768 -persist << EOF

    set datafile separator ","
    set datafile missing ""
    set size 1.0, 1.0
    set origin 0.0, 0.0
#   set key at 0,0
    set key spacing 1.3
    set key horiz ins top center box lw 0
    set border 3

    set multiplot
    set size 0.45,0.45
    set origin 0.02,0.02 #bottom left Tl H2
    set grid

    set xdata time
    set timefmt "%d/%m/%y"
    #   set xtics format "%d/%m/%y" 
    set xrange ["$thirty_days_ago":"$todays_date_4_2"]
    set xtics rotate nomirror
    set xtics "$thirty_days_ago",172800,"$todays_date_4_2"

    set yrange [0:30]
    set ytics nomirror
    set title "Tl201 CFOV $l H2" font "Helvetica"
    plot \
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tl_h2_qc_s' using 1:17  pt 5 ti ' NEMA Diff (%)' with linespoints,\
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tl_h2_qc_s' using 1:16 lt 3 pt 5 ti 'NEMA Int (%)' with linespoints,\
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tl_h2_qc_s' using 1:12 lt 4 pt 5 ti 'CoV (%)' with linespoints

    set origin 0.02,0.52 #top left Tl H1
    set title "Tl201 CFOV $l H1"
    if ("$camera2" eq "blue1" || "$camera2" eq "red1") plot \
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tl_h1_qc_s' using 1:17  pt 5 ti ' NEMA Diff (%)' with linespoints,\
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tl_h1_qc_s' using 1:16 lt 3 pt 5 ti 'NEMA Int (%)' with linespoints,\
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tl_h1_qc_s' using 1:12 lt 4 pt 5 ti 'CoV (%)' with linespoints

    set origin 0.52,0.02 #bottom right Tc H2
    set title "Tc99m CFOV $l H2"    
    plot \
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tc_h2_qc_s' using 1:17  pt 5 ti ' NEMA Diff (%)' with linespoints,\
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tc_h2_qc_s' using 1:16 lt 3 pt 5 ti 'NEMA Int (%)' with linespoints,\
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tc_h2_qc_s' using 1:12 lt 4 pt 5 ti 'CoV (%)' with linespoints

    set origin 0.52,0.52 #top right
    set title "Tc99m CFOV $l H1"    
    if ("$camera2" eq "blue1" || "$camera2" eq "red1") plot \
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tc_h1_qc_s' using 1:17  pt 5 ti ' NEMA Diff (%)' with linespoints,\
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tc_h1_qc_s' using 1:16 lt 3 pt 5 ti 'NEMA Int (%)' with linespoints,\
        '/misc/${camera2}_data/${camera2}/${qc}/tc_h1_qc_s' using 1:12 lt 4 pt 5 ti 'CoV (%)' with linespoints

    unset multiplot


EOF
```

When I run this on my machine I get the following output[image]

Why is this so messy? When I click the toggle grid button, I lose 3 of my 4 plots, but one plot looks more like it should. [image]

Here is the output from the test command. Looks fine
[image]

It doesn't seem to be a problem with gnuplot but with my linux settings. I am running RedHat Client release 5.8. Any ideas what is going on here

Comment: What does it look like if you just issue the `test` command?  That should help you adjust your pointsize settings.

Comment: Does the test command look normal to you? I am new to gnuplot and wonder whether the settings have been personalised so that the output on my computer differs from others. I have tried yum install and have the same problem

Comment: moadeep -- Yeah, `test` looks OK to me.  You could try running it on your other machines (where the script works as you expect) and see if you notice any real differences...If there aren't differences, that seems quite strange...